# Draw horizontal / vertical marker lines in a Chaco plot

Tags: plot, chaco

I am looking for some help to draw a marker line in a Chaco plot (equivalent to QwtPlotMarker https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot_marker.html).

The marker line is just an horizontal or vertical line that is drawing between ymin/ymax or xmin/xmax whatever the zoom factor is.

Comment: A good place to ask Chaco questions is https://groups.google.com/g/ets-users/about

Comment: thanks for the advice Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

Question asked on groups.google.com/g/ets-users/about following Jonathan's advice.
Answer from Corran Webster :

you probably want a CoordinateLineOverlay.  Unfortunately, it seems to be missing from the overlay documentation, but the class definition is here: https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/master/chaco/overlays/coordinate_line_overlay.py#L14 and an example of how to use it is here: https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/b89b2e5c0935d79eef9e2928d32356c4043dc624/examples/demo/coordinate_line_overlay_demo.py

There is also the LineInspector tool if you want a line which tracks the mouse position, and of course the Grid class for drawing multiple vertical/horizontal gridlines.
-- Corran

Comment: For the record, thread at https://groups.google.com/g/ets-users/c/gkk0DY7bpZY/m/t6vg1jUBCAAJ